# How to make multiple charts with d3.chart using nested data

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, charts, nested

I'm trying to create several charts using the d3.chart framework. This seems like it would be a common use case: the whole point of d3.chart is for the charts to be reusable after all! If you can just point me to an example that would be awesome (:

I went through this (https://github.com/misoproject/d3.chart/wiki/quickstart) tutorial to create a very basic "circle graph". (I copied the code exactly). Now what I want to do is create a separate chart for several sets of data.
I edited it slightly. 
Before editing, to set up the chart we called:

```
var data = [1,3,4,6,10];

var chart = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .chart("Circles")
    .width(100)
    .height(50)
    .radius(5);

chart.draw(data);
```

I tried to change it to:

```
var data = [{key:1, values:[1,3,4,6,10]}, 
{key:2, values:[5,2,10,8,11]}, 
{key:3, values:[1,5,9,16,12]}]

var chart = d3.select("body")
  .selectAll("chart)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("svg")
  .chart("Circles")
    .width(100)
    .height(50)
    .radius(5);

chart.draw(function(d) { return d.values; });
```

This doesn't work however. You can see the corner of a circle in 3 diferent places, but
the rest of it is cut off. However if replace

```
chart.draw(function(d) { return d.values; });
```

with

```
chart.draw([1,3,4,6,10]);
```

it correctly generates 3 circle graphs, all with that one dataset. And when I add

```
chart.draw(function(d) { console.log(d.values) return d.values; });
```

The console shows the 3 arrays I'm trying to pass it! I don't understand what is happening here that's breaking the code. Shouldn't it be the exact same thing as passing the actual arrays to 3 separate charts?

Here's a link to the JS bin with it set up: http://jsbin.com/jenofovogoke/1/edit?html,js,console,output Feel free to  mess around with it!

The code is wayyy at the bottom.

I'm pretty new to java script and d3, and entirely new to d3.chart. Any help would be super appreciated!

Comment: I cleaned up that bin a bit, by linking to d3.chart instead of including the code. See http://jsbin.com/jenofovogoke/3/edit?html,js,output. If you open the **browser's** JavaScript console, you'll see "Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute cx="NaN", which probably explains why your circles are all showing up on top of each other.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for cleaning it up! This doesn't really address my problem though: the reason it isn't finding cx is because it isn't accessing the data correctly (cx relies on the value). If you place a console log of chart.data right underneath the dataBind under initialize, you can see that it logs the data as "function(d) {return d.values;}" like it were a string, rather than logging the actual array that corresponds to d.values. My question is why isnt it/how can i make it access the data properly.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out what's going on, but without success. Somewhere along the line your `xScale` seem to break. But unfortunately I can't find where that happens. Maybe someone else here has better luck.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen In case you're interested  I figured out the answer! Unfortunately d3.chart's draw function can only accept a data object, so rather than pass it a function that calculates the data object I looped through and manually set the data for each chart. And it works now! (: Yay! Now if only I could figure out how to have d3 chart layers within layers I'd be set.. :P

Comment: I tried removing the data access function, but clearly must've done something wrong. :-/  Great that you figured it out, and came back to self-answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked Irene Ros, who helps run d3.chart, and she informed me that the problem is that d3.chart's draw method can only take an array or  a data object- it cannot take a function. She gave me a few helpful hints for ways to get around this: by using a transform function to edit my data within the chart, rather than using a function, or by creating a chart that holds multiple charts (see https://gist.github.com/jugglinmike/6004102 for a great example of this).

However in the end I found the simplest solution for me was to manually set the data. It feels like a bit off a hack because D3 does this for you already, but it was much simpler than changing the whole set up of my chart, and allows for nested data (yay!).

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .selectAll("svg")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("svg");

svg.each(function(d, i) {
  var chart = d3.select(this)
    .chart("Circles")
    .height(50)
    .width(100)
    .radius(5)
  var data = d.values;
  chart.draw(data);
});
```

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be `svg.each`?